# How to use variable type 'any' as key to a value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to JS and React. I'm trying to display a certain image based on the public domain.

I have a dictionary in JS which looks like this:

```
export const urls = {
    'jp' : '/images/tea.svg',
    'us' : '/images/coffee.svg',
}
```

In my .tsx file, I null-check the public domain.

```
const domain = process.env.PUBLIC_DOMAIN !== null ? process.env.PUBLIC_DOMAIN : 'us';

'''

<Image src={urls[domain]}/>
```

My editor is giving an error at the usage of 'domain':

```
Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)
const domain: string | undefined
```

I've also tried type-casting process.env.PUBLIC_DOMAIN to a string, but it did not work either.

Please let me know how to resolve this, or if there's a better approach. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: check if its undefined

Comment: Because env variables optional by default. Either extend the global type in .d.ts file or add `!` operator to tell to the compiler, this variable has value don't worry. 
---
After that, you should narrow the type by `keyof typeof urls`

Comment: Use `process.env.PUBLIC_DOMAIN != null` not `process.env.PUBLIC_DOMAIN !== null` to ignore `undefined` values (not just `null`)